# Incorrect information counting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to pull information from the database between 01.01.2021 and 31.12.2021

The first day of the week is Monday (not Sunday)

This is a fairly easy task, but I have problems with it, I get information only from 07.01.2021 to 16.09.2021
I do not fully understand how these functions work, so please help me

```
SELECT
a.ModifiedOn AS Week,
COUNT(a.ActivityId) AS Count
FROM ActivityPointer AS a 
WHERE 
a.ModifiedOn >= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, -1,DATEADD(week, 0, '2021')), 0) 
AND
a.ModifiedOn <= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, -5,DATEADD(week,43, '2021')), -1) 
AND
a.ActivityTypeCode IN ('4201','4210','4212') 
AND a.OwnerId IN('3C696B18-BFF4-E911-A68A-005056A18C45',  
'DDD1597F-4FCD-E411-80D3-0050568973A1',   
'0AD3654A-7517-E011-B418-00505689002A',   
'98FA2C51-A296-EB11-A6AD-005056A18C45',   
'56C940A2-B396-EB11-A6AD-005056A18C45',   
'379C0CE5-D3D2-E911-8105-02BF0A0AC819') 
GROUP BY a.OwnerId,a.OwneridName,a.ModifiedOn
ORDER BY ModifiedOn desc
```

But I am specifically interested in this part of the code

```
a.ModifiedOn >= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, -1,DATEADD(week, 0, '2021')), 0) 
AND
a.ModifiedOn <= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, -5,DATEADD(week,43, '2021')), -1)
```

Comment: if you've got specific dates you want to search between why do anything with DATEADD and DATEDIFF? why not just put the dates into your query

Comment: Doing date arithmetic in T-SQL isn't just complicated, it also precludes the (efficient) use of indexes. You're usually better off having your queries of the form `where [datecolumn] >= @fromParam and [datecolumn] < @toParam`, and passing the parameters from client code (or variables you set in T-SQL, if you really have to). If widely varying ranges can be used an `option (recompile)` may be necessary to ensure the engine doesn't try to fit one plan to every situation.

Comment: Thank you friends, thanks to you and this forum I can easily learn sql and learn a lot of new information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify your query by placing your date information into the query:

```
a.ModifiedOn >= '2021.01.01'
AND
a.ModifiedOn <= '2021.12.31'
```

Comment: This is not a [safe date format](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166771/what-date-time-literal-formats-are-language-and-dateformat-safe). Prefer a format like `20210101`, which is.